# What is Google expecting from a /token enpoint?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, actions-on-google

I'm developing a Google Actions Application and a Webhook to make this app comunicate with a server with client credentials. When implementing the OAuth & Google Sign-in flows with my server I can't seem to find what is the response the Google side is waiting from /token endpoint, it is supposed to return the access token that then will be used in every request made from the action (..if I got that part correctly..). I currently returning a ContentResult with the appropriate StatusCode (i think) and a json body with the access token it is supposed to return. Something like this:

```
ContentResult result = null;
data.Add(@"token_type", @"Bearer");
data.Add(@"access_token", FAKE_ACCESS_TOKEN);
data.Add(@"refresh_token", FAKE_REFRESH_TOKEN);
data.Add(@"expires_in", FAKE_SECONDS_TO_EXPIRATION);

jsonResponse = data.ToString();

result = new ContentResult
{
     Content = jsonResponse,
     ContentType = "application/json"
     StatusCode = (int?)HttpStatusCode.OK
};

return result;
```

The [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/assistant/identity/google-sign-in-oauth?creation=no&oauth=code) on this part seems to be vague. Maybe Someone could help me figure it out ? Thanks in advance

Comment: This looks good. Try `bearer` instead of `Bearer`. `Bearer` is expected when sending the token in the header but if I remember correctly, the OAuth2 identity provider is expected to return `bearer`.

Answer (score 1):

[Solved] Thank you for your answers. I got the problem solved by changing the return type of my Post Method to "JsonResult" instead of "ContentResult".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the code flow, then your /token endpoint has two things it needs to handle:

- Exchanging an *auth code* for the *access token* and *refresh token*
- Exchanging the *refresh token* for a new *access token*

The responses for each are similar, but slightly different (most notably, the second one shouldn't return a new *refresh token*).

For an *auth code* exchange, the parameter `grant_type` that is sent to you will have a value of "authorization_code", so you'll return JSON looking something like this:

```
{
"token_type": "Bearer",
"access_token": "ACCESS_TOKEN",
"refresh_token": "REFRESH_TOKEN",
"expires_in": SECONDS_TO_EXPIRATION
}
```

for a *refresh token* exchange, the `grant_type` parameter will have a value of "refresh_token", and the response will roughly be the same, but without a refresh token:

```
{
"token_type": "Bearer",
"access_token": "ACCESS_TOKEN",
"expires_in": SECONDS_TO_EXPIRATION
}
```